# CMake: embedding path to imported shared library in executable

Tags: cmake

I have an external library. That I am bringing into a CMake build using an imported library target. The build is baking in relative path to the shared library with respect to the `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`.
I have something like this:

```
add_library(libstring UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libstring PROPERTIES
 IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external/libstring.so"
  )
add_executable(my_exe "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_exe.cpp")
target_link_libraries(my_exe PRIVATE libstring)
```

Then `ldd my_exe` returns

```
external/libstring.so => not found
```

If instead of linking to the imported target I link directly to the library giving the absolute file path it works fine.

```
target_link_libraries(my_exe PRIVATE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external/libstring.so")
```

Then `ldd` returns

```
libstring.so => /<bin-dir>/external/libstring.so (0x00007fce27537000)
```

In both cases `rpath` is set to `/<bin-dir>/external`.

When linking to an imported target how to make CMake bake in just the name of the library in the executable?

Note, that when the imported library path is outside of the binary tree, then the absolute path is baked in the executable.

Comment: CMake replaces the RPATH info with the value of the `INSTALL_RPATH` property when the install steps are run... the binaries in the binary directory are not meant to be distributed.

Comment: This is during the build step. I am using the executable afterwards during the build for other targets.

Comment: Why mark the lib as type `UNKNOWN`, if it's obvious, it's a shared lib (.so extension)? Not sure if changing this already helps; otherwise there's the [`BUILD_RPATH` target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/BUILD_RPATH.html) that could be modified. There are 2 other things that catch my eye: `"${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external/libstring.so"` why is this relative to the toplevel build dir? I'd expect libs that are provided to be stored in the source tree. `"${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_exe.cpp"` sources in the binary dir are unusual to. Ensure you've got good a reason for this

Comment: The library is in the binary tree. I think it may be a problem with the linker or this particular library, because with other libs it does not do that.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that it is not CMake causing this problem, but this particular library.
With Unix Makefiles, CMake passes to the linker relative paths with respect to the `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`.

```
../external/libstring.so
```

Or with Ninja it passes relative to `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`.

```
external/libstring.so
```

The linker then bakes-in this whole relative path. Not the name of the library only.

Other libs are not affected even when passed to the linker like that. I don't know what is different with this library.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set [IMPORTED_NO_SONAME](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_NO_SONAME.html) property for the library:

```
set_property(TARGET libstring PROPERTY IMPORTED_NO_SONAME TRUE)
```

Documentation for this property says:

> Set this property to true for an imported shared library file that has
> no [soname](https://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Library#soname) field. CMake may adjust generated link commands for some
> platforms to **prevent the linker from using the path to the library** in
> place of its missing soname.